# Chrome Display Scaling Issue

Tags: google-chrome, scaling, hdpi

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Chrome display scaling is not working as it did in 16.04 with"--force-device-scale-factor=n". 
Now everything is too much tiny in Chrome. What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

For my ubuntu 19 and Chrome version 77.0.3865
I needed to put quotes around the parameter.

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable "--force-device-scale-factor=1.3" %U
```

this worked for me!